# Requiring an API call to use HTTPS with Apigee

Tags: https, apigee

I'm building a proxy using Apigee that transmits sensitive data. I need to ensure that clients of this API use HTTPS.

I've coded a Raise Fault policy that does something like this

proxies/default.xml

```
<PreFlow name="PreFlow">
    <Request>
        <Step>
            <FaultRules/>
            <Name>Require-HTTPS</Name>
            <Condition>request.scheme != "https"</Condition>
        </Step>
    </Request>
    <Response/>
</PreFlow>
```

policies/Require-HTTPS.xml

```
<RaiseFault async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Require-HTTPS">
<DisplayName>Require-HTTPS</DisplayName>
<FaultRules/>
<Properties/>
<FaultResponse>
    <Set>
        <Headers/>
        <Payload contentType="application/json">\{ 
"status" : 400,            
"message" : "Sensitive transactions may only be executed over HTTPS",
}
      </Payload>
        <StatusCode>400</StatusCode>
        <ReasonPhrase>Requires HTTPS</ReasonPhrase>
    </Set>
</FaultResponse>
<IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</RaiseFault>
```

The problem is, the fault is always raised, whether I use HTTP or HTTPS to access.
I can see in the debugging console that the condition in proxies.xml always resolves to true, whether I use HTTP or HTTPS to access the API. In fact, the request.scheme always seems to be HTTP.

However, I do see the following header using HTTPS access that's not present using HTTP

```
X-Forwarded-Proto :     https
```

Can I depend on this header to enforce HTTPS only access to my API? Or is there some other recommended way to do this?

Comment: I have an implementation that seems to work by using this condition instead
    `<Condition>request.header.X-Forwarded-Proto != "https"</Condition>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try detecting the virtual host rather than the scheme by using the virtualhost.name variable (default or secure).

However, I suggest you create a two proxies -- one for https and one for http.  This will remove the possibility of a consumer slipping past your conditional roadblock.  Click on the word "default" under Proxy to edit the entire proxy file and scroll down to the HTTPProxyConnection

```
<HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>/testme</BasePath>
    <VirtualHost>default</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
</HTTPProxyConnection>
```

Just remove the VirtualHost for default and the consumer will no longer be able to connect using https.  I beleive you can then create a second API with the same path, only then remove "secure" and create a RasieFault without a condition.  Worst case, you can rely on the Apigee error if you just disable default in your API.